# Azure AD - Allow users to update their Job Title / Department

Tags: azure-active-directory

I have Azure AD Premium and O365 Enterprise License assigned for my users. Is it possible for me to allow the users to update their AD profile information, such as Job title, Department ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible for me to allow the users to update their AD profile
>   information, such as Job title, Department ?

Yes, you could make this, you need to [Assign roles to users](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-users-assign-role-azure-portal). Because it requires a Global administrator or user administrator to add or update a user's profile information.
For the details, you could read this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/fundamentals/active-directory-users-profile-azure-portal?context=azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/context/ugr-context).

Comment: Just adding to solution from @SunnySun, it may be obvious but worthwhile to mention that Global Administrator and User Account Administrator are both very highly privileged roles which give permissions to perform a lot more.. across all Azure AD users/applications etc. (than just updating own profile info).. If it's really critical and no other way gets suggested.. you can consider another option of creating a custom API/Web app which could help with some self service use cases like this one to update profile info.